# spring-mvc @Size annotation does not resolve error message correctly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to use Validator from Spring with `ValidationMessages.properties` to define error messages defined in javax annotations (`@NotNull`, `@Size` etc). However, instead of resolved message the raw string (like "Size.firstName.length") is printed. Moreover, tomcat shows a warning which says

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [/WEB-INF/messages/] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/messages/, locale en_US
```

Additionally, I also checked similar questions in here but nothing worked. Lets say this is a simple Person POJO.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Size.firstName.length")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10)
    private String lastName;

    public User() {};

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

...
}
```

and related config the related jsp file is like below,

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"spittr.web", "spittr.data"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactory() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validatorFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**registerForm.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spittr</title>
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/user.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <sf:form method="POST" commandName="user">
            First Name: <sf:input path="firstName"/>
                        <sf:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/><br/>
            Last Name: <sf:input path="lastName"/>
                       <sf:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </sf:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ValidationMessages.properties**

```
firstName.size=First Name must be between {min} and {max} charatecters long.
```

And ValidationMessages.properties is under

```
- webapp
  - WEB-INF
    - messages
      - ValidationMessages.properties
```

So, as I said if firstName is invalid, error message is not rendered and raw string of "Size.firstName.length" is shown.

Comment: include `{}` braces around your message `@Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "{Size.firstName.length}")`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work too. I tried that before

Comment: Do you want to have locale specific messages?

Comment: well that is my second step after resolving the default properties. the things is I followed every type of configuration but nothing is working.

Comment: A ResourceBundle is loaded by the classloader. `WEB-INF` is not part of the classpath. Your properties file should under `WEB-INF/classes`. Assuming it's in `WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar/messages/ValidationMessages.properties`, its basename is `foo.bar.messages.ValidationMessages`.

Comment: You are using Spring and as such a `MessageSource`. However your basename is wrong it should be the basename of a file NOT a directory. Remove the messages directory and rename `ValidationMessages.properties` to `messages.properties` and in your `MessageSource` configuration remove the ending `/`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed `messages` directory under `WEB-INF` and renamed  `ValidationMessages.properties` as `messages.properties` however nothing is changed.

Comment: If that is all you do indeed nothing will change as you also have to reconfigure the `MessageSource`...

Comment: @M.Deinum I mean I also removed `/` from MessageSource configuration

Comment: That still isn't going to work as `WEB-INF` isn't the classpath and the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` is only capable of loading files from the classpath (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring delegates the message lookup to the configured `MessageSource` it doesn't use the `ValidationMessages.properties` for that. (That is what default bean validation does!).

However the configuration of your `MessageSource` is wrong. The [`baseName`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename-java.lang.String-) should be a file name NOT a directory. Next you are using a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` which is only capable of loading files from the [classpath](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource). Reconfigure your `MessageSource`.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Now rename your `ValidationMessages.properties` to `messages.properties` and put it in `src\main\resources\`.

Comment: ahh finally. This works. Thanks a lot. But the resources I was reading they all use ValidationMessages.properties without initializing any MessageSource but don't know why mine wasn't working. And book says if I want to use internalization I need to create `ValidationMessages_es.properties`. So how can I achieve this internalization if I am only giving names rather than directory names ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments that is the default Bean Validation. When using Spring to bootstrap the validation AND you have a `MessageSource` configured that will be used instead of the default. If you don't want that don't configure a `MessageSource` and the default will apply.

Comment: now I understand. I achieved to use the default one as well. Thanks a lot : )